# What happened to the previous users badge?

Tags: discussion, support

I earned the **`Marshal`** badge recently and then I noticed it awarded to only 1 time, I,m sure this badge is already earned by few users. What happened to the previous users badge ?

Comment: I don't recall anyone having that badge...

Comment: @MPD Is there is anyway to check the history for this badge, I think this can be answered only with history, otherwise simply I will delete this question.

Comment: I also thought a couple of people had that badge a while back. Might be wrong though...